# Perl If Else Statement

Tags: perl, if-statement

Alright, so this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl


my $argument1 = $ARGV[0];
open (LOGFILE, "<$argument1") or die "Can't find file";

open FILE, ">>output.txt" or die $!;


while(<LOGFILE>){
if (/UNSUCCESSFUL/){
    print FILE "ERROR in line $.\n" if (/Error/);
    print "script unsuccessful \n";
    else:
print "script successful \n";   }
```

}

```
close FILE;
close LOGFILE;
```

The problem, I think, is with my if else statement.  If there is not the word "unsuccessful" in the text that is read in, it should simply print out "Script successful."  However, if the read in file does contain "unsuccessful," then it should record where in the file the word "Error" appears and write this out to a file.  Help?!

Sample input:

bar foo bar bar bar
error: will not compile
bar bar bar bar bar
attempt unsuccessful

Comment: This will print `script successful` for all the lines in the input file that does not contain `UNSUCCESSFUL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not wish to print `"script successful"` for all the lines in your input that does not contain the word `"UNSUCCESSFUL"`. Instead, save the printing for last, and if you have no errors, print the success message.

```
my @errors;
while(<LOGFILE>) {
    if (/UNSUCCESSFUL/) {
        push(@errors, "ERROR in line $.\n") if (/Error/);
    }
}

if (@errors) {
    print for @errors;
} else {
    print "script successful\n";
}
```

Comment: Okay, that took care of printing for each line. However, it is not writing out to a file.  for some reason, I don't think my append function is working.  It also now says that a script which has "unsuccessful" in it is still successful

Comment: `print FILE for @errors` if you want it to your output file. I am giving you the information you need to solve your issues, not a ready-baked copy/paste solution.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry.  I'm just really unfamiliar with Perl's syntax.  Sorry.

Comment: @user1440061 Yes, I know. A line in your input must contain *both* `UNSUCCESSFUL` and `Error` to be added to the print, e.g. `UNSUCCESSFUL foo: Error at bar`. As per your specifications. If that is not correct, you need to give some sample input.

Comment: Yes, sorry, maybe I was not clear.  Error and unsuccessful will be at different lines.  I am adding sample input to my original question

Comment: If it is the last line that contains "unsuccessful", you will need to capture "error" independently. You have two restrictions here, and you will need to decide how they are combined. If they always come together (both errors and unsuccessful in file), you need only check for errors. On the other hand, it may be that you do not care about errors unless there is an "unsuccessful" message at the end, in which case you may decide not to print.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a bit off:

```
if (/UNSUCCESSFUL/){
    print FILE "ERROR in line $.\n" if (/Error/);
    # Print to your file
    print FILE "script unsuccessful \n";
    #print to screen
    print "script unsuccessful \n";
} else {
    # Print to your file
    print FILE "script successful \n";
    #print to screen
    print "script successful \n";
}
```

Comment: that just gets me script successful printed about 100 times and then script unsuccessful at the bottom.  and it doesn't write out to the file

Comment: Yes, but what was the consequence of "else:" (with colon)? A label, doing nothing (colon, the statement deletion operator???)? What could have detected the problem? Using a "strict" mode? How can we learn to fish?